# What was Merleau-Ponty a realist about?

Tags: realism, merleau-ponty

I think I have read the claim that he was both an idealist and a materialist and not a dualist, but what is mind independent for him, trees, colours, electrons?

Comment: Why not turn to [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/merleau-ponty/#NatuPercStruBeha) first? "Organic life and human consciousness are emergent from a natural world that is not reducible to its meaning for a mind; yet this natural world is not the causal nexus of pre-existing objective realities". His is not the kind of realism that can be usefully flashed out in terms of traditional cliches, and that kind of nuance will be largely lost here. He is more in line with earlier aspirations to dissolve the subject-object divide and devise an alternative to both traditional positions.

Comment: cliche is a poetic word @Conifold

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "realist about X" as meaning "thought of X as real".

But then, your OP speaks of "mind-independence" as a criteria for what is "real". Merleau-Ponty considered that any knowledge we have of the world is derived from our mental representation of the world, that the whole world *as we see it* is by definition mind-dependent, and that philosophy is about our presence in the world. It's not about trying to figure out "how does the world look like when no one is looking."

So I would say that your criteria of mind-independence does not really work for Merleau-Ponty. It is not his concern.

Comment: i doubt no-one has applied 'realism' to his work, and if i find it a helpful phrase, so much the better if anyone can

Comment: @prof_ghost Words can indeed be useful, at least when we know what they mean.

Comment: trying to figure out how the world is?

Comment: @prof_ghost The world is fine. *We* are the problem. What is "mind independent" is independent from us, and therefore it's none of our concerns.

Comment: so nothing we manipulate is indepednent of us?

Comment: @prof_ghost By definition, when you manipulate something, that thing is in your hand.

Comment: but then it does resist our movements to an extent. don't worry about it; i hope i haven't offended you

Comment: @prof_ghost Not to worry, i'm not easily offended. Yes, the world resists us. Or perhaps better, we try to resist the world and it fights back.